# jQuery adding a class - all methods I've tried remove the class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, flip, toggleclass

I'm working with a 3D rotating button in which each face has a different phrase, but both are links to the same URL. I initially was rotating the cube button with a plain old css :hover, but I noticed that when you click the button it resets. It should only rotate back to its starting position if your mouse is no longer on the button.

I have created a pen that uses all of my markup and styling, and I've tried four methods of adding a class called 'flip' to style on hover, but each of these four methods have the same effect as the plain old css :hover method, they reset on a mouse click. I've commented #2, 3, and 4 out in the pen just because they are all yielding the same result, and the first is just a simple 'toggleClass' method. Here's the four JS snippets and a link to the pen.

```
// #1 Story Button Toggle Class On Hover To Rotate - Resets on Click
    $('.story-button').hover(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('flip');
      return false;
  });

// #2 Story Button Add/Remove Class On Hover To Rotate - Resets on Click
$('.story-button').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass('flip');
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass('flip');
  }
);

// #3 Story Button Add/Remove Class on 'mouseover To Rotate - F's Up the markup/styles on mouseover
$('.story-button').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).removeClass().addClass('flip');
    }).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass().addClass('flip');       
});

// #4 Story Button Add/Remove Class on 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' To Rotate - Still Rotates back on click
 $('.story-button')
    .mouseenter(function() {   
        $(this).addClass('flip');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('flip');
 });
```

And the link to the pen: http://codepen.io/andandandandrew/pen/OPXOxP?editors=011

Thanks in advance for the help/advice!

PS, If anyone has any idea why this would work on codepen but not on my local mamp server (building a wordpress site, using codekit with no JSHint errors when compiled/minified) that would be super.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the hover event is on the element that is being transformed if you add a `div` around the `button` and listen for the hover on the `div` then you shouldn't have a problem.

HTML:

```
<div class="btnContainter">
   <button class="story-button">
      <a class="front" href="javascript:(void)">FRONT</a>
      <a class="back" href="javascript:(void)">BACK</a>
   </button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.btnContainter {
   display: block;
   width: 15em;
   height: 3em;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.btnContainter').hover(function () {
    $(this).children('.story-button').toggleClass('flip');
    return false;
);
```

[**codePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxBPma)

Comment: Ok so this is working nearly close to perfect. I've updated my pen to use the toggleClass version with your updates, and to show you kind of how these buttons will be used. The problem now it, that when you hover on any of the button (class="button-container") it flips any and all buttons with that class. Is there a way to only target the one you are hovering on?

Comment: Also, any clue why this would work in codepen with the exact same markup that is in my wordpress template? Here's a link to a screenshot of the markup the PHP spits out: http://i.imgur.com/mPphpAH.png

Comment: You are a freaking wizard! The pen works on its own, but I made a new pen that actually mimics the page template I've created for this. Basically this JS function is happening within a masonry board. Check out this new pen, and if you have any idea what's up with it, you will most definitely get some credit on this site.

http://codepen.io/andandandandrew/pen/EagxeL

Comment: Yeah I saw that one, which works fine when it's not inside a masonry container. Take a look at this new pen if you don't mind, where I've used that function, but it's not toggling the class because (I believe) the buttons are within a masonry board.

New Pen: http://codepen.io/andandandandrew/pen/EagxeL

Comment: @andandandandrew The problem was that your hover method was on `.btnContainter` not `.flip-container`. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbExNy