# Why can't I add a toggleClass within a masonry container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, masonry

Are there any masonry experts out there? I'm having major troubles adding a toggleClass to a div that allows users to flip a button in 3D space. I've created a pen that has the exact same markup and styles pulled from my wordpress template and sass files.

I'm initializing masonry with jquery, and its piece is working just fine, but when I try to add in the following script to toggle a class while hovering on a div that falls inside the masonry container, it does not toggle.

Here's the JS code (graciously donated by user imtheman) for the toggle:

```
$('.btnContainter').hover(function () {
      $(this).children('.story-button').toggleClass('flip');
      return false;
});
```

Here's a link to the thread on how we got there: [jQuery adding a class - all methods I've tried remove the class on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553757/jquery-adding-a-class-all-methods-ive-tried-remove-the-class-on-click/27554267?noredirect=1#comment43642805_27554267)

And here's the link to the codepen that has some commented out description in the js panel of the particular problem: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/andandandandrew/pen/EagxeL)

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that your hover method was on `.btnContainter` not `.flip-container`.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbExNy

Comment: Fixed it. Apparently the little toggleClass function needs to be in the same JS file as the one as the masonry file. I've been doing conditional loading of scripts (ex. masonry.js) because I only use it on one page and don't see the need to pull it in on every page. I think I'm going to re-evaluate that and just have codekit compile everything together. I'll probably put some logic in the masonry inititalize to only work on pages with certain ID's on the <body>

imtheman, **is the man**.